# Does WP, php, or a current framework (woofoo / genesis, etc). Offer a way to schedule text / bg color changes?

Tags: themes, framework

I would like to build a site for a religious group that follows a Church calendar year that highlights seasons by different colors.   Is there a way with existing WP / php / css / framework to schedule a different color profile for a theme based on the date?

casey

Comment: It would be better to ask how this could be done. Asking for links is rather not constructive, links die sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create different style sheets for each color profile, and load those depending on which month it is. Here's a basic example showing how you could load a halloween.css file for october, and an xmas.css file for december. The code below would go in your themes functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'seasonalCSS');
function seasonalCSS()
{
    // register stylesheets to be loaded safely
    wp_register_style('halloween', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/halloween.css");
    wp_register_style('xmas', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/xmas.css");

    switch(date('n'))
    {
        case 10: // if it is october...
            wp_enqueue_style('halloween'); // load halloween.css
            break;

        case 12: // if it is december...
            wp_enqueue_style('xmas'); // load xmas.css 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm glad you were able to read my question and answer it.  I intended to ask it broad enough for any type of answer.   Follow - up [ a php question ] can a specific date be set for the `switch(date('n'))` ?

Comment: Tell me more about your intentions. Putting a specific date in as the paramter for the switch would negate the whole purpose of checking what month it is, and loading a stylesheet for that month. Are you asking how to check a specific date(to the day) maybe?

Comment: The Church Calendar changes on specific dates...  a past example. I'd be setting all these dates once a year but then the changes would be automatic. 
There are typically six or more changes in the liturgical calendar year.

Advent
November 28, 2010 through December 23, 2010  |  Christmas
December 24, 2010 through January 6, 2011  | Time after Epiphany
January 9, 2011 through March 6, 2011  | Lent
March 9, 2011 through April 20, 2011